# Journey JSON in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm playing around with Journey on node and I only realized that the router is interpreting JSON requests objects as the value of the key that has an empty value:

In other words, when i post to the server a JSON object I get the following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/> post /events
... {url : "test"}
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Feb 2012 00:42:38 GMT
Server: journey/0.4.0
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 67
Connection: keep-alive

{
    event: {
        _id: '10tPxx',
        resource: 'Event',
        {url : "test"}: ''
    }
}
```

As you can see the whole object is being considered as a string.

Here's my Journey related code:

```
exports.createRouter = function(resource){
    var router = new (journey.Router)({
        api: 'basic'
    });
    router.path(/\/events/, function(){
....
        this.post().bind(function(res, event){
            console.log(event);
            resource.create(event, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    return res.send(500, {}, {error: err.error});
                }
                res.send(200, {}, { event: result});
            });
        });
...
    });
    return router;
};
```

The printout of the console is:

```
{ '{url : "test"}': '' }
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: When you post, are you setting the `Content-Type` request header to 'application/json'? It looks like the json is getting parsed using `querystring.parse` instead of `JSON.parse`. Revelant code: https://github.com/cloudhead/journey/blob/master/lib/journey.js#L331

Comment: The http request shows: `Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8` I'm just using the http-console.

Comment: I wonder if the `;charset=utf-8` is messing up the Regex test.

Comment: Yup it does, it should be exactly application/json

Comment: Oh, cool. Maybe check that you have an up-to-date version of Journey. If that line I linked to is the right place, then it looks like having charset shouldn't break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the json is getting parsed using querystring.parse instead of JSON.parse.

Make sure that you are properly sending a 'content-type' header with 'application/json'.

Comment: Just to clear things up, the problem was indeed in the way I was using the http-console tool (tool to send http requests), it was adding `;charset=utf-8` to the content-type by default. In order to solve this in one shot, I had to insert the following command in the terminal: `http-console --json localhost`. Hope this finds well those in need.